# How to adjust height & width of a widget to the window size?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer

I am working on a project where I am making a UI in `qt designer` and writing its code in `python`. I haven't set any height and width properties of ui widget or window in qt designer. When I am starting it, its not covering the whole window. Below is the code:

**app.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from ui.test import Ui_MainWindow

class Login(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
main_window = Login()
main_window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**test.py** (which has been converted from test.ui)

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1177, 480)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.table_widget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.table_widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 1161, 421))
        self.table_widget.setRowCount(20)
        self.table_widget.setColumnCount(20)
        self.table_widget.setObjectName("table_widget")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

When I am starting the code, it looks like below:

[image]

In above image I can move the scroll bar to see all the rows and columns but if I click on maximize window it looks like below:

[image]

But in above image height and width remains same. How can I make it full screen so that widget height and width matches with the window size. Please help. Thanks

Comment: You need to use a layout manager. See [Resizing widgets in PyQt4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13564550/resizing-widgets-in-pyqt4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add table_widget to centralwidget to do so you should use layout.

Here is information about the [Layout Management](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html). You can also set the layouts in Qt Designer ([Using Layouts in Qt Designer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-layouts.html)).

```py
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.table_widget)
        self.centralwidget.setLayout(layout)
```

The whole code.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QVBoxLayout


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1177, 480)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.table_widget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        # adding table_widget to central widget
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.table_widget)
        self.centralwidget.setLayout(layout)
        # end
        self.table_widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 1161, 421))
        self.table_widget.setRowCount(20)
        self.table_widget.setColumnCount(20)
        self.table_widget.setObjectName("table_widget")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: It's important to note that modifying files generated by pyuic is highly discouraged.